# Crash - EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS specialized _VariantDictionaryBuffer.nativeUpdateValue(_:forKey:)

Tags: swift, crash, twilio, exc-bad-access

I have a crash but I'm not sure what caused it.

I using Twilio framework, and all work fine, but I get a weird prod crash
I look like it a Dictionary related issue:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000e711dbea8
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182696654 object_getClass + 64
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1833f3e18 _CFRelease + 1060
2  TestApp                       0x100cae408 specialized _VariantDictionaryBuffer.nativeUpdateValue(_:forKey:) (TicketsManager.swift)
3  TestApp                       0x100b4ba94 specialized ChatManager.getAndJoinDialog(roomId:onSuesscs:onFaild:) (ChatManager.swift:798)
4  TestApp                       0x100c5e7f0 specialized ChatMessagesManager.getAllMessagesFromServerForTicket(_:) (ChatMessagesManager.swift:164)
5  TestApp                       0x1009d7ca0 ChatViewController.loadAllMessagesFomServer() (ChatViewController.swift:460)
6  TestApp                       0x1009feed8 partial apply for closure #1 in ChatViewController.viewWillAppear(_:) (ChatViewController.swift:234)
7  TestApp                       0x100aee754 closure #1 in static Utils.performTaskOnMain(_:) (Utils.swift:84)
8  TestApp                       0x1009b778c thunk for @callee_owned () -> () (QRCodeViewController.swift)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x182dcd088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x182dcd048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x182dda378 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1028
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182dd9f10 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183073120 _pthread_wqthread + 1268
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183072c20 start_wqthread + 4
```

TicketManager func:

```
func getAndJoinDialog(roomId : String,onSuesscs: @escaping (() -> Void),onFaild: @escaping (()-> Void)) {
    if let channel = self.getDialog(roomId) {
        self.addDialog(channel)
        self.joinDialogWithBlock(channel, successBlock: onSuesscs, failBlock: { (_) in
            onFaild()
        })
        return
    }
    self.chat?.channelsList()?.channel(withSidOrUniqueName: roomId, completion: { (result, channel) in
        if result.isSuccessful() && channel != nil{
            self.addDialog(channel!)
            self.joinDialogWithBlock(channel!, successBlock: onSuesscs, failBlock: { (_) in
                onFaild()
            })
        }else {
            DDLogError("getAndJoinDialog error: \(String(describing: result.error))")
            onFaild()
        }
    })
} <- **Crash on this line**
```

add dialog func

```
func addDialog(_ dialog:TCHChannel)
{
    self.dialogs[dialog.sid ?? ""] = dialog
}
```

I'm not sure what happened that can be caused this crash

Comment: I recommend you open this as an issue on GitHub on the [Twilio iOS chat example](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-ios/issues). The SDK team often check that repo and answer or help out.

Comment: Are you sure this crash came from Twilio?, In the stack trace it looks like the crash came from the TestApp - (my app)

Comment: Are you able to use an empty string for a dictionary key?

Comment: yes, I check now on the playground and you can enter an empty string into a dictionary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not that great at iOS and I don't know what's going on here then. If it's a problem with Twilio Chat, then I'd raise it on GitHub. If not, you can hope someone else can help out here.